# How to display hovered point value in Highcharts Crosshair

Tags: highcharts

[As shown in screenshot I need my crosshair to move across the points but the tooltip value is snap to next value even the crosshair is not reached that point.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRipI.png)I am facing an issue in highcharts. I want when I hover around the chart then crosshair should reflect the value of current point which is being hovered. As shown in code currently its changing values in mid way which is not reflecting right value as respect to crosshair.

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    tooltip: {
     snap: -1,
        crosshairs: true
    },
    xAxis:{
     crosshair: {
                interpolate: true,  
                color: 'gray',
                snap: false
            },
    },
plotOptions: {

    line: {
        marker: {
            enabled: false
        }
    },
   
},
    series: [{
    marker: {
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            },
         step:'left',
        data: [0, 1, 0,  1,  0, 1, 0]
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you set the `xAxis.crosschair.snap` equal to `false`. Actually, you can remove the `snap: false` definition, because it's set to `true` by default. Then it should behave just like you want.

**[EDIT]**

If you would like to show current crosschairs xAxis value, it's not implemented in Highcharts, but Highstock has its own `xAxis.crosschair.label` property which serves the feature you need. Here is the example and documentation:

http://jsfiddle.net/hzcuf68y/

https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.crosshair.label

If you don't want to change the Highcharts for Highstock, you can refer to this demo, where the crosschairs and labels are rendered manually: http://jsfiddle.net/mr1c03ae/

**Live example:** https://jsfiddle.net/n7bawfcg/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.crosshair.snap

Comment: Hi daniel_s thanks for replying. But if I set snap to false. Then my crosshair do not hover in between the points. Crosshair jump from one point to the next point. I want my crosshair to move around and shows the exact value where the crosshair exactly is irrespective of points.

Comment: Hi @daniel_s thanks for updating the answer but still, I am facing a problem as shown in screenshot. I have added a screenshot in question to make it more clear.

Comment: Actually, the tooltip is generated for every point that is defined in your series definition. If there are points like `x:0 y:0` and `x:1 y:1`, the tooltip always will be created for one of them, so how would you like to present the tooltip for some point which is not defined at all? The crosschair is made for the case like that (to point the current axis value, not series point),  so if you would like to use tooltip for that, I'm affraid that you can only interpolate the series points as you did below.

Answer (score 0):

After alot of research I got the solution just posting here if someone may face the same problem. http://jsfiddle.net/F4e2Y/70/

```js
function interpolate(data) {
    var resolution = 0.1,
        interpolatedData = [];
    data.forEach(function(point, i) {
        var x;
        if (i > 0) {
            for (x = data[i - 1].x + resolution; x < point.x; x += resolution) {
                interpolatedData.push({
                    x: Highcharts.correctFloat(x),
                    y: Highcharts.correctFloat(data[i - 1].y),
                });
            }
        }
        interpolatedData.push(point)

    });
    return interpolatedData;
}


var data = [{
    x: 0,
    y: 1
}, {
    x: 2,
    y: 0
}, {
    x: 4,
    y: 1
}, {
    x: 6,
    y: 1
}, {
    x: 8,
    y: 0
}, {
    x: 10,
    y: 1
}];



Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart:{
zoomType: 'x',
},
    tooltip: {
        shared: true
    },

    xAxis: {
        crosshair: true
    },

    series: [{
    
       step:'left',
        data: interpolate(data),
    }]

});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 300px; height: 300px; margin: 1em"></div>
```